# PHP Make HTTP GET Request in Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap Modal dialog that appears when you click on a link on the body of the page. It contains a button to make a call via a VOIP service - here's the modal code:

```html
<div class="modal" id="callModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Call Customer</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Calling Fred Flinstone . . . </p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <a href="<?php echo $contact1CallBack ;?>" id="callContact"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Make Call</button></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

When the user clicks the Make Call button at the moment it calls the URL in the same window - I would like to remain in the modal window and make the call the HTTP url in the background but not sure how to do this?

Comment: What have you attempted so far? Post your JavaScript.

Comment: What $contact1CallBack variable contains? And why use button within anchor tag? Any one of those is sufficient to achieve what you wish to.

Comment: You are using an anchor tag, it will redirect you to the given `href`.

Comment: The modal code is not relevant to your question, the javascript, and what the new url returns, is. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve You could use AJAX to get the new url in JS. I would use JQuery for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**From this:**

```
<a href="<?php echo $contact1CallBack ;?>" id="callContact"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Make Call</button></a>
```

**To change this:**

```
<button type="button" id="makecall" class="btn btn-success">Make Call</button>
```

Jquery:

```
$("#makecall").click(function(){

 $.ajax({

           url:$yoururl/method,
           data:{},
           method:"POST",
           success:function(data){

            }

       });

    });
```

This will keep you rmodal as it is.
In success funciton inside ajax call, you can put code to do what you want to after call is made successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You can make call of api using Ajax

```
<a href="javascript:" onclick="callapi(<?php echo $contact1CallBack ;?>);" id="callContact"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Make Call</button></a>
```

And call API by this code

```
<script>
function callapi (api) {

                $.ajax({
                    url: api,
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    crossDomain: true,
                    success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                        console.log(data);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.log(errorThrown);
                    }
                });

        }
    </script>
```

So it will not reload your page and call API in background

Hope this help you